# Classification with BERT

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I'm working on a classification problem with text data and before I go the LLM route, I want to test using something less expensive. I've never applied BERT before and was looking for some assistance. I have 2 dataframes. One has 2 columns (Identifier, Description), the other also has 2 columns (Category, Description). I've created the embeddings for my first dataframe with the following methodology (example dataframes included):

```
from transformers import BertModel, BertTokenizer
import torch
import time
import pandas as pd

# Build reference dataframes
dict1 = {'identifier':['Sean', 'Ashok', 'Kathy'], 'Description':['I have experience building data pipelines and cloud architecture in AWS, Azure, Snowflake, and Databricks',
                                                                 'Project Manager with advanced skills in JIRA, SCRUM, and Agile Delivery',
                                                                 '5 years of experience in web development and design, building high performing and robust interfaces.']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

dict2 = {'Category':['Data Architect', 'Project Manager', 'Web Designer'], 'Description':['Able to leverage their computer science and design skills to review and analyze the data infrastructure of an organization, plan future databases, and implement solutions to store and manage data for organizations and their users',
                                                                                          'Responsibility of the planning, procurement and execution of a project, in any undertaking that has a defined scope, defined start and a defined finish; regardless of industry',
                                                                                          'Able to develop applications using a client–server model. The applications typically use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in the client, and any general-purpose programming language in the server.']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)

# Tokenize skills
df1['token_vector'] = [tokenizer.encode(f, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512, truncation=True, pad_to_max_length=True) for f in df1['Description']]

# Get token ID's
df1['token_ids'] = [tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(f) for f in df1['token_vector']]

# Get torch tensors
df1['tensors'] = [torch.tensor(f).unsqueeze(0) for f in df1['token_ids']]

# Get word embeddings
df1['embeddings'] = [model(f).last_hidden_state[0] for f in df1['tensors']]
```

Do I need to repeat this process for df2 and compare each embedding from df1 to every embedding from df2 with a cosine similarity and create a label based on the shortest distance? I'm a bit confused on how I can potentially classify the descriptions into categories, any advice would be appreciated.